# Выдает ошибку : ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' -'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
import math
f = open('D:/Python/info/input.txt', 'r')
g = f.read(256)
a = g[4] + g[5]
b = g[11] + g[12]
c = g[18] + g[19]
if g[5] == ';':
    a = g[4]
if g[12] == ';':
    b = g[11]
if g[19] == ';':
    c = g[18]



if g[4] == '-':
    a = g[5]
    if g[12] == ';':
        b = '-' + g[11]
    if g[11] == '-':
        b = g[12]
    if g[19] == ';':
        c = '-' + g[18]
    if g[18] == '-':
        c = g[19]




d = int(b)*int(b) - 4*int(a)*int(c)
if int(d) > 0:
    x1 = (-int(b) + math.sqrt(d))/(2*int(a))
    x2 = (-int(b) - math.sqrt(d))/(2*int(a))
if int(d) < 0 :
    x1 = 0
    x2 = 0
if int(d) == 0 :
    x3 = (-int(b))/(2*int(a))
output = open('D:/Python/info/output.txt', 'w')
if int(d) > 0 : 
    output.write('x1 = ' + str(x1) + '; ' + 'x2 = ' + str(x2))
if int(d) < 0 :
    output.write('Корней не существует, так как дискриминант меньше нуля')
if int(d) == 0 : 
    output.write('x1,2 = ' + str(x3))
print('Ваши результаты готовы!')
output.close()
f.close()
```

вот сам код. Выдает вот такую ошибку :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Что исправить то, помогите пожалуйста, заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' -'` произошла в строке:

```
d = int(b)*int(b) - 4*int(a)*int(c)
```

Причина в том, что в функцию `int` попала строка `' -'`, т.е. в одной из переменных  `b`, `a` или `c` точно есть строка, что не является числом